# Play a song on a Visual Basic Program?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, audio

I am currently working on a project and for one of the factors I need to add music in the background of the program. Everything works correctly except the music does not play.

I have added the command My.Computer.Audio.Play("Path of File", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete")

I have also tried the variation of adding the .wav / .mp3 to the projects resources and then using, My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.musicfile, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete")

And in the end, these **both** do not work? Is there another way to add the music to my Visual Basic program. (I am using the Visual Basics Form in Microsoft Visual Studio.)

[This is what is in my Debug\Soundtrack\mmusic.mp3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ayWK.png)

Comment: i'll see what I can do

Comment: The sound must be `.wav` extension using `My.Computer.Audio.Play()` function.

Comment: I have already figured it out if you read the comment section below ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `My.Computer.Audio.Play("Path of File", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete")` won't let you play any other audio format than **.wav**

You can play **.mp3** by using the `MediaPlayer` provided

---

Follow these steps:

1. Go to **Project** menu
2. click on **Add Reference...**
3. go to **COM** tab
4. select **Windows Media Player (wmp.dll)** from the list
5. click **OK**

---

Now the coding part:

You need to import `WMPLib`

add this line:

```
Imports WMPLib
```

And then this, on the `form_load`

```
 'add a media player
    Dim Player As WindowsMediaPlayer = New WindowsMediaPlayer
    'assign the location of the song to be played
    Dim SongLocation = "D:\Music\Single\Skrillex 2 Hours HQ Longest On Youtube).mp3" 'any song you want to play
    'play the song
    Player.URL = SongLocation
    Player.controls.play()
```

And that's it, when you load the form, the song will play itself. Hope it helped you :)

---

**EDIT**

---

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the folder where your song is located ("mmusic.mp3" <-- this file)
2. Copy the song
3. Go to **Debug** folder.
   Here's what my debug folder's location looks like :

> F:\Visual Studios 2010\Projects\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\bin\Debug

4. Paste the song in the **debug** folder.

---

Now change your code to this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports WMPLib 

Public Class Launcher 
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Player As WindowsMediaPlayer = New WindowsMediaPlayer 
        Dim SongLocation = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"mmusic.mp3")
        Player.URL = SongLocation
        Player.controls.play()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PlaySound(sSoundFile)
    Dim oPlayer As Object : oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    oPlayer.URL = sSoundFile
    oPlayer.controls.play()
End Sub
```